# How to get object field in Parse

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Here is my query for a particular User:

```
  var query = new Parse.Query("User");

  query.get(userId, {
    success: function(user) {
      if (user === undefined){
        response.success("No such user with this ID: " + userId)
      }else{
        response.success("successfull " + user.get('authData')); //   authData is undefined whereas name, minAge and other primitive types are working fine
      }
    },

    error: function() {
      response.error("user lookup failed");
    }
  });
```

That `user.get('authData')` is returning `undefined`, however other primitive type fields such as name and age are working fine.

I am thinking it is because `authData` is object

[image]

How can I access it?

Comment: I am using this in my parse.com app and it works, even `userToSave.get("authData").facebook.id` works. Are you using parse.com or Parse Server? Something might be wrong with Parse Server and then you should [report it](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues). In my particular case, I am calling this from User beforeSave hook and I get the user this way: `var userToSave = request.object;` and it works.

Comment: or maybe using masterkey for the query could help